# Как удалить заголовок "Описание" и раздел "похожие товары"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу удалить заголовок "описание" и раздел "похожие товары" - подскажите пожалуйста, в какой папке искать?
[Ссылка на страницу.](https://bb-talkin.ru/product/set-kite/)

Comment: Вопрос не совсем корректен. Он может быть в любой папке. Надо смотреть на структуру самого проекта (через исходный код этого не видно).

Comment: Прошу прощения. Это CMS WordPress, плагин woocommerce.

Comment: Ну вот теперь правильно сформулируйте вопрос и вставьте его в гугл “how to remove related products in woocommerce”, помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая первая ссылка в Google по запросу `how to remove related products woocommerce`

Вставьте этот код в functions.php вашей дочерней темы

```
/**
* Remove related products output
*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

Можете попробовать вот так убрать заголовок вкладки "Описание"

```
/**
* Remove tab heading
*/
add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', '__return_null');
```

Comment: /**
* Remove related products output
*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );

Сработало, благодарю!

Comment: Заголовок убрал с помощью: 

add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', false);

Comment: Ну по сути тоже самое, хорошо что решился вопрос